# Should I move out my bell pepper plants?

Tags: repotting, bell-peppers

[image: Bell Pepper Plants]

Should I be moving my bell pepper plants into bigger pots now or should I let them grow more? If I should be moving them, how should I space them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their first 'adult' leaves are only just developing. I would wait until they've grown at least two sets (ie. 4) adult leaves. They will then be much more likely to survive the repotting.

Once they get a lot bigger than that, you'll have trouble separating them.

I usually plant outside and have about 18in (1-2ft) between individual plants. With pots I usually go for about 3 plants in a 12in pot - but they don't grow as well as in a bed with more spacing.

Comment: Agreed on all this. Also: I suggest rotating which side of the pot faces the window.

Comment: agree :-)  Those don't look too bad, but when they're leaning like that, turn the pot.